# Error: No such command 'flower'. Did you mean one of these? worker

Tags: django, celery, flower

I am trying to use django + celery + rabbitmq + flower, but after i downloaded flower using pip3:

```
Collecting flower
  Using cached flower-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (459 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7" in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flower) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: humanize in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flower) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flower) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado<7.0.0,>=5.0.0; python_version >= "3.5.2" in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flower) (6.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client==0.8.0 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flower) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: vine<6.0,>=5.0.0 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click-didyoumean>=0.0.3 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (0.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: billiard<4.0,>=3.6.3.0 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (3.6.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click-repl>=0.1.6 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.0 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kombu<6.0,>=5.0.0 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (5.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from click-repl>=0.1.6->celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from click-repl>=0.1.6->celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: amqp<6.0.0,>=5.0.0 in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from kombu<6.0,>=5.0.0->celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (5.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit->click-repl>=0.1.6->celery>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"->flower) (0.2.5)
Installing collected packages: flower
Successfully installed flower-0.9.5
```

in my virtual env, when i tried to use

```
 celery -A myshop flower
```

with celery and rabbitmq running i got this error:

```
Error: No such command 'flower'.

Did you mean one of these?
    worker
```

I have done this in the same directory:

```
/home/denys/env2/myshop/myshop
```

end when i am using celery --help, there is no flower command:

```
Commands:
  amqp     AMQP Administration Shell.
  beat     Start the beat periodic task scheduler.
  call     Call a task by name.
  control  Workers remote control.
  events   Event-stream utilities.
  graph    The ``celery graph`` command.
  inspect  Inspect the worker at runtime.
  list     Get info from broker.
  logtool  The ``celery logtool`` command.
  migrate  Migrate tasks from one broker to another.
  multi    Start multiple worker instances.
  purge    Erase all messages from all known task queues.
  report   Shows information useful to include in bug-reports.
  result   Print the return value for a given task id.
  shell    Start shell session with convenient access to celery symbols.
  status   Show list of workers that are online.
  upgrade  Perform upgrade between versions.
  worker   Start worker instance.
```

And also i tried to use:

```
celery flower -A myshop
```

What should i change? Thank you)

Comment: Pleas read https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#usage. Flower is not installed

Comment: I removed it and installed one more time:`(myshop) denys@denys-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC:~/env2/myshop/myshop$ pip3 show flower
Name: flower
Version: 0.9.5
Summary: Celery Flower
Home-page: https://github.com/mher/flower
Author: Mher Movsisyan
Author-email: mher.movsisyan@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/denys/env2/myshop/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: humanize, celery, tornado, pytz, prometheus-client
Required-by: `

Comment: The [1.0.0](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029#issuecomment-873243638) release lets us use [celery>=5.0.5](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/1.0/requirements/default.txt)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the latest version of `flower` [doesn't yet support celery v5.0.0](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/89e71c8c00dcb51bc584e908fc6b2ba97706e89a/.github/workflows/build.yml#L12) as of 10/1/20.

As Артур mentioned, dropping to 4.4.7 should resolve the issue.

Comment: Upgrading to Celery 5.0.0 breaks flower due to change in celery.bin.base module. #1029
https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029

Comment: The [1.0.0](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029#issuecomment-873243638) release lets us use [celery==5.0.5](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/1.0/requirements/default.txt)

Answer (score 2):

Use celery 4.4.7 version  mb  will solve the problem !

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
celery flower -A myshop --address=127.0.0.1 --port=5555
```

You can `address` to whatever is the IP of your `rabbit server (in case it is not on local)` .

Also try if you will get `flower` listed when you execute `pip freeze` .